# The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling the multiple file upload request

Tags: java

Can anyone please help in resolving error? Trying to upload multiple files in server folder and filename is in database but server throwing following error -

> HTTP Status 500

type Exception report

message

> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.

exception

> java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   F:\eworkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\UploadServlet30\uploadFiles
>   (Access is denied)
>     net.codejava.servlet.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:53)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) root
>   cause
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   F:\eworkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\UploadServlet30\uploadFiles
>   (Access is denied)    java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
>     java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>     java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:425)
>     net.codejava.servlet.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:53)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

### Controller class

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    News news = new News();

    // gets absolute path of the web application
    String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
    // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
    String savePath = appPath + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIR;

    // creates the save directory if it does not exists
    File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdir();
    }

    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        System.out.println("partttttttttt"+part.getName());
        String fileName = extractFileName(part);
        System.out.println("fle Name-----"+fileName);
        // refines the fileName in case it is an absolute path
        fileName = new File(fileName).getName();
        System.out.println("fle Name-----"+fileName);           
        part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
        news.setFileName(fileName);
    }

    news.setNewsTitle(request.getParameter("newsTitle"));
    news.setNewsDesc(request.getParameter("newsDesc"));


    String newsId = request.getParameter("newsId");

    if(newsId == null || newsId.isEmpty())
    {
        dao.addNews(news);
    }
    else
    {
        news.setNewsId(Integer.parseInt(newsId));
        dao.updateNews(news);
    }
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_NEWS);
    request.setAttribute("newsList", dao.getAllNews());
    view.forward(request, response);

}

/**
 * Extracts file name from HTTP header content-disposition
 */
private String extractFileName(Part part) {
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String s : items) {
        if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

and the dao

```
public void addNews(News news) {
    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO NEWSMASTER(NEWSID, NEWSTITLE, NEWSDESC,FILENAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        pStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        pStmt.setInt(1, news.getNewsId());
        pStmt.setString(2, news.getNewsTitle());
        pStmt.setString(3, news.getNewsDesc());
        pStmt.setString(4, news.getFileName());
        pStmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

### model class

```
public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception Message shows "Access is denied". So it seems that you don´t have the rights to read this directory or file.

Comment: so what i have to do?

Comment: You (or your admin) need to set the appropriate rights which allow you to read the uploadFiles directory/file. Obviously, it´s a directory inside the eclipse workspace. So I suggest you set rights to access the entire workspace.